# Newbie, emulator is not working

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-7.1, windows-phone

I am completely a newbie in Windows phone app development.

I followed this [tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff402526%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) to develop my 1st Windows Phone app. When I am ready to run my 1st app, I selected **Debug->Start debugging** on the top toolbar of visual studio 2010, but I got the following dialog:

[image]

It complains that my working machine(Lenovo W510) does not have the graphics processing unit. What can I do for this if I would like to run my app on a emulator?

Comment: what if you press yes or no buttons?

Comment: the same problem here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16012172/windows-phone-emulator-issue-in-windows-7

Answer (score 0):

When clicking on "Yes", it should launch the emulator anyways but with limited functionality. (no extensive 3D, things like that)

If it does *not* succeed in launching the emulator then you will have to find a system with better graphics capabilities. However, considering the W510 runs an nVidia Quadro FX 880M, I'm pretty sure it should be able to run the emulator just fine. Have you checked your GPU driver yet?

Comment: Yes, the emulator is started. I am actually seeking a way to completely get rid of this warning popup. Do you mean I should update my GPU driver?

Comment: As mentioned in [this question here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16012172/windows-phone-emulator-issue-in-windows-7), updating the GPU driver may solve your problem, yes.

Comment: The W510 has NVIDIA Quadro FX 880M graphics, which should have a WDDM 1.2 driver available for download and installing it should work.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same issue with the SDK on an older machine. For XNA and otherwise smooth effects / transitions in Silverlight projects the emulator requires `Windows Phone Emulator requires a DirectX 10 or above capable graphics card with a WDDM 1.1 driver`.

The issue I had is that my graphics card (some integrated Intel) didn't have WDDM 1.1 drivers. In this case, if you are looking to develop XNA projects, the only two solutions are

- upgrade your graphics card
- or buy a real device on which you can test.